# Memory exhausted while running phpunit

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm using pest PHP testing framework for unit testing in laravel. Memory is getting exhausted each time when my test cases are run. How can I increase my memory limit for test cases? Below I'm attaching a screenshot of my terminal output [image]

Comment: Please set memory_limit=-1 and try.

Comment: I am not sure what are you setting up for your tests to pass, but you are using 128 Mb of memory... there is a leak there or you are setting up too many things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the memory of `PHP`, but depending on how many tests you have, you should look into if you have memory leaks or data being kept in memory that should not.

```
php -d memory_limit=2048M ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Comment: We run with php artisan test. How the limit apply?

Comment: php -d memory_limit=2048M ./artisan test. Should do it